# What type of phrase is this?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

When saying someone is 'full of themselves', what type of phrase is this? Is there some sort of literary device that describes a phrase that literally means something else from what the user is trying to convey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a person is full of himself, the "full of himself" is acting as a predicate adjective, or identifying the noun on the other side of the linking verb (be verb). Think of it this way: person = full. "Of himself" is a an adverbial prepositional phrase changing the meaning of the adjective "full."... (0;

So...He is a "full" man, and what he is full of is "himself." In other words, he is a very conceited man.

Comment: The question is: 'Is there some sort of literary device [I assume 'term'] that describes a phrase that literally means something else from what the user is trying to convey?'

Answer (score 1):

This is usually called a [figure of speech.](http://grammar.about.com/od/rhetoricstyle/a/20figures.htm) A figure of speech is a phrase or combination of words which has a distinct meaning separate from the obvious meaning you would get from the individual words.

For example, if I say "hit me with your idea" I mean "tell me about your idea" not "physically strike me with your idea."

It's rhetorical language, generally used to convey an idea in a new or different way. When overused it may become a [cliche](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cliche).